# How to make the program spit-back any of the "if" statements when 1 or 2 is pressed?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make the program print any of the "if" statements when 1 or 2 is        pressed but goes to print the else statement even when 1 or 2 is pressed. Can someone please let me know what I am not doing right. I would really appreciate this.

Thank you.

```
import java.io.* ;

public class MyFan
{

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        try
        {
          InputStreamReader FanSpeed = new InputStreamReader(System.in) ;
          BufferedReader strInput = new BufferedReader (FanSpeed) ;

          System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 2: ") ;

          int inputData = strInput.read();

           if(inputData == 1)
           {System.out.println(" Fan is turned on to speed of " + inputData);}

           else if(inputData == 2)
            {System.out.println(" Fan is turned on to the speed of " + inputData);}

         else{System.out.println(" Fan not turned; turn the fan on by pressing 1 or 2 ") ;}

          }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("You have to turn the Fan on") ;
        }

      }

}
```

Comment: Are the cases for 1 and 2 actually reached if 1 or 2 are entered?

Comment: `int inputData = strInput.read();` probably should be `int inputData = strInput.readInt();`

Comment: Set a breakpoint at your `if` statement and see what `inputData` is.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29), The method `read` returns the character read, not its numeric value. Perhaps you can hotfix this by using

```
int inputData = strInput.read() - '0';
```

to achieve the desired result, but I suggest some more appropriate parsing of the input.

Comment: How does `char - '0'` work to convert a char into its numeric value?

Comment: @Rogue In general, it does not; but if `char` is in the range '0',...,'1', the calculation wil map `char` to its numeric value due the position of the characters in the ASCII table. I admit that the approach is quite hackish.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to get the user input as an `int` would be to use `Scanner` instead:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int inputData = scanner.nextInt();
```

`BufferedReader::read()` does indeed return an `int`, but it represents the character input, not the numeric value. Using `Scanner::nextInt()` will return the actual `int` entered.

Comment: Although I once tried "Scanner" but I also retained the "BufferedReader" but it didn't work. I will try the Scanner now without the BufferedReader let me see what it gives. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, I removed the "try-catch" block and the "read()".

Comment: @user3616650 Awesome! I'm glad this fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that your reader is returning `-1`, or the actual character value (`48`, etc) from the `read()` function, thus always going to the `else` statement due to being the end of the buffer or unexpected value. `read()` will output the next character value, so while it can be valid as an int, I would use `nextInt()` on some different reader such as a `Scanner`.

If you continue wanting to use the BufferedReader, try parsing the character:

```
char next = strInput.read();
int inputData = Integer.valueOf(Character.toString(next)); //Will throw NumberFormatException if not a number
```